# What exactly the getSplits() method returns?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What exactly the getSplits() method returns? 
According to apache docs it returns the array of InputSplit, what does that mean?

Does it returns the block of file bytes on which mapper is going to run??

1. Lets say we have 3 files of 50MB each, then it returns bytes of 64MB(50MB+14MB 2nd file)at [0],64MB(36MB 2nd + 28MB of 3rd), 36MB(third file) and each is processed by 3 different mapper?
2. If we have one big file of 120MB then it returns the block of 64MB for same file?

I am even not sure of what I am asking is logical or not, I new to Hadoop stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getSplits()` return the splits - metadata about parts of the files. Each map process one split.

If your file is large, it is divided into parts with the size of the HDFS block (at least 64MB). In your second example it will be two splits of 64MB and 56MB. Although, nowadays the recommended block size is 128MB or even 256MB.

If the file is smaller then the block size, it will be in the separate split. In your first example you will have three splits of 50MB each. If you want to combine them and process in one Mapper, you could use [CombineFileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html) ([example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-hadoopcombine/)).

Answer (score 0):

An input split in MapReduce is the unit of parallelization for the mapper phase. If you have ten input splits then you will have ten mappers. In the general case a file block will map to an input split.

An [InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html) object contains information about the split, but not the split data itself. Depending on the subclass (such as [FileSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.html)) this information could be items such as the location of the split and how large it is.